# Git - How to revert empty merge commit?

Tags: git

Someone created an empty merge commit(`develop` to `broken-branch`).

When I try to run `git revert <commit> -m 1` I receive a message:

```
$ git revert <commit> -m 1
Already up to date!
On branch my-brach
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/broken-brach'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I need to remove this commit since merging this branch to `develop` simply reverts all changes from `develop` that were ignored during the empty merge.

Also, the commit is already published :(

UPDATE: The commit is shared across the team. And there are plenty of commits after that

Comment: What do you mean under "empty merge commit"? There either could be merge or not. Or you mean that there is commit without any message (explanation)?

Comment: That commit does not introduce any changes, there no any diif, just two parent commits. As I understood someone encountered merge conflicts and simply cleared all local changes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need to remove this commit ...

Actually, you *don't* need to *remove* it.  Removing it would solve one problem but can create others.

> ... since merging this branch to develop simply reverts all changes from develop that were ignored during the empty merge.

I believe I know what you mean to say here.  That's not quite correct technically, but captures the essence of the problem.

> Also, the commit is already published :(
>
> UPDATE: The commit is shared across the team. And there are plenty of commits after that

This is where the *can create other [problems]* part I mentioned in my first sentence comes in.  It may be too hard to remove the senseless merge, so you might want a different approach.  First, let's describe the problem *properly*, though.

We start with two lines of development, with a series of commits on each, and two branch names to identify the *last* commit in each of these lines of development:

```
       o--o--o   <-- develop
      /
...--*
      \
       o--o--o   <-- br2
```

I've used one of the two names you used (`develop`) and a more neutral name for the second branch (`br2`).  Note that both branches descend from some common starting point, which I have marked here as commit "star" `*`.  I've arbitrarily chosen to represent the branches as having three commits since that point on each branch, though any number of commits would work.  The key is that this starred commit is the best *common ancestor* of the two branches.

If we were to do a normal merge operation now, we could pick one of the two branches with `git checkout` or `git switch` and run `git merge` on the other branch.  To represent our mistake, though, I'm going to first create a new *name*, `mistake`, and point it at the last commit that is on branch `br2` as of this point:

```
       o--o--o   <-- develop
      /
...--*
      \
       o--o--o   <-- br2, mistake (HEAD)
```

We now have *three* branches, including the branch on which we'll make a mistake (on purpose): we will run:

```
git merge -s ours develop
```

This will create a new *merge commit*, which I will represent using the letter `M`.  A merge commit is like any other commit in that it has a source code snapshot of all files and a first parent, but unlike ordinary commits, it then has a *second* parent too.  The first parent of new merge `M` will be the commit that is at the tip of `br2` (and currently at the tip of `mistake`) and the second parent will be the commit that is at the tip of `develop`.  For easier reference later, let me call these two commits `A` and `B`:

```
       o--o--A   <-- develop
      /       \
...--*         M   <-- mistake (HEAD)
      \       /
       o--o--B   <-- br2
```

Because of the `-s ours` option, the *snapshot* in commit `M` exactly matches the snapshot in the last commit on `br2`.  That is, if we get the actual hash IDs of `M` and `B` and run:

```
git diff <hash-of-M> <hash-of-B>
```

the *difference* will be *completely empty*.  (If it's not *completely* empty, we can still have a problem later, it's just that the problem might be a little smaller.)  **If we had left out the `-s ours` option, we would have a normal merge and we would not have set up a trap for ourselves in the future.**  But we are trying to reproduce your issue.

Now let's make more commits on both `develop` and `mistake`, in the usual way:

```
       o--o--A--C--D--E   <-- develop
      /       \
...--*         M--F--G--H   <-- mistake
      \       /
       o--o--B   <-- br2
```

If we now check out one of these two—for instance, `develop`—and run `git merge` on the other, Git does the same sort of thing we *should have* let it do last time: it finds the *merge base* between commits `E` and `H`.  The problem here is that this is commit `A`, not commit `*`.

What Git does now, then, is compare what's in the merge base—commit `A`—with what's in the two branch-tip commits.  That is, it runs, in effect:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-A> <hash-of-E>   # what we changed
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-A> <hash-of-H>   # what they changed
```

Now, what exactly *is* in commit `H`?  Well, commit `H` is built by taking what's in `M`—which matches what's in `B`—and making some change in `F`, then making some change in `G`, then making some change in `H`.  So the "what they changed" part starts with *removing whatever is in the two `o` commits along the top line*, then adding some more changes.

Meanwhile, what's in `A`-vs-`E` is whatever got changed in `C`, `D`, and `E`.  Git combines these two changes: *add C+D+E, but also add M+F+G+H*.  The *add M* step means *take away what's in the two top-line `o` commits*.

Note that the *merge base* between commits `A` and `B` is commit `*`.  If we had let Git combine the work in the three commits leading to `A` with the work in the three commits leading to `B`—if we had not *made a mistake*, in other words—we'd be in great shape now.  The snapshot in `M` would combine these bits of work.  It would not *take away* changes from the two unnamed `o` commits along the top.  But we deliberately *didn't* use commit `*`.  We made the snapshot in `M` match the snapshot in `B`.  **We set up a time bomb, and our later merge explodes the time bomb.**

Note that this problem is independent of the *branch names*.  If we didn't use the name `mistake`, we would now have:

```
       o--o--A--C--D--E   <-- develop
      /       \
...--*         M--F--G--H   <-- br2
      \       /
       o--o--B
```

This is the same *commit graph* and therefore contains the same time bomb.  The bomb is embedded in the commits.  The *names* we use to *find* the commits are quite irrelevant.

## How to fix the problem

There are several different ways around this problem.  None of them is the Single One Right Way.  *All* of them need to take the mistake into account.  The mistake was to set up a time bomb, so that this future merge will *drop* several commits—the unnamed ones along the top row.

All ways to fix this involve creating new commits.  (That's pretty much the only thing you ever *do* in Git, after all.)  The question is which new commits to create.  We can choose any of several actions:

- Copy a whole bunch of commits, fixing our earlier mistake as we go.
- Go ahead and merge now, then copy the individual commits that got dropped.
- Temporarily "fake out" the lack of a merge, using `git replace`.  (I'm not going to show this method, as it's complex and has repeatability issues.)
- Others that you can imagine and try out for yourself.

Suppose we start with this:

```
       o--o--A--C--D--E   <-- develop
      /       \
...--*         M--F--G--H   <-- mistake
      \       /
       o--o--B   <-- br2
```

That is, even if we used the name `br2` all along, let's create a new name `mistake` pointing to commit `H`, then use `git branch` or `git reset --hard` to force the name `br2` to point back to commit `B`:

```
git checkout -b mistake br2; git branch -f br2 <hash-of-B>
```

Now we'll `git checkout` commit `B` under the name `br2`:

```
git checkout br2
```

to get:

```
       o--o--A--C--D--E   <-- develop
      /       \
...--*         M--F--G--H   <-- mistake
      \       /
       o--o--B   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

#### Method 1: copy commits, omitting the mistake

We can now simply copy every commit *after* `M`, without bothering with commit `M`, using an en-masse `git cherry-pick`:

```
       o--o--A--C--D--E   <-- develop
      /       \
...--*         M--F--G--H   <-- mistake
      \       /
       o--o--B--F'-G'-H'   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

This might have a bunch of merge conflicts.  If so, we'll have to solve each one.

Having done this, we can now erase the *name* `mistake` entirely, if we wish, and pretend commits `M-F-G-H` never even existed:

```
       o--o--A--C--D--E   <-- develop
      /
...--*
      \
       o--o--B--F'-G'-H'   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

This amounts to removing the merge via `git rebase`.  The rebase command is in essence just an en-masse cherry-pick with some branch name juggling, which is exactly what we just did.  Now we can merge commits `E` and `H'` in the normal way, using commit `*` as their merge base.

Note that we can leave the name `mistake` around, and maybe create a new name `br3`, so that we get:

```
       o--o--A--C--D----E   <-- develop
      /       \          \
...--*         M--F--G--H \ <-- mistake
      \       /            \
       o--o--B--F'-G'-H'----M2   <-- br3 (HEAD)
```

or use `develop` as the branch that acquires the merge:

```
       o--o--A--C--D--E-----M2   <-- develop (HEAD)
      /       \            /
...--*         M--F--G--H / <-- mistake
      \       /          /
       o--o--B--F'-G'---H'   <-- br3
```

The advantage to creating a new name is that this way, branch names only move forward.  Any time we use `git branch -f` or `git rebase` to move a branch name "backwards" first, then forwards, that means that every *clone* of our repository must adjust any work they have done that depends on the names moving forward.

#### Method two: merge, then copy commits to fix the mistake

Alternatively, let's look at starting with this:

```
       o--o--A--C--D--E   <-- develop
      /       \
...--*         M--F--G--H   <-- br2 (HEAD)
      \       /
       o--o--B
```

and just doing the merge now.  We run `git checkout develop` and then `git merge br2` and get:

```
       o--o--A--C--D--E---M2   <-- develop (HEAD)
      /       \          /
...--*         M--F--G--H   <-- br2
      \       /
       o--o--B
```

where commit `M2` *drops* commits `o-o` from the top, just as we noted.  So now let's just cherry-pick them in:

```
git cherry-pick <hash1>
git cherry-pick <hash2>
```

The merge itself and the two cherry-picks *might* have merge conflicts.  If so, that's OK; we just solve them.  Now we have:

```
       o--o--A--C--D--E---M2-o'-o'  <-- develop (HEAD)
      /       \          /
...--*         M--F--G--H   <-- br2
      \       /
       o--o--B
```

and the snapshot in the last `o'` commit has what we want.

#### Method 3: copy the `develop` branch to bypass the mistake

Last, we can use one other mass copy trick.  Instead of mass-copying `F-G-H` onto the end of `B` (whether by `git cherry-pick` or by `git rebase`), let's mass-copy *the entire top line*.  For sanity sake, let's use a new name, keeping `develop` as the old one, for the moment.   We'll call the new branch `fixup` and we'll point it to commit `*`, which is before the screwup starts:

```
     ..................   <-- fixup (HEAD)
     .
     . o--o--A--C--D--E   <-- develop
     ./       \
...--*         M--F--G--H   <-- br2
      \       /
       o--o--B
```

Now, with `fixup` checked out (as indicated by `HEAD` above), we force Git to copy commits `o-o-C-D-E` using `git cherry-pick`:

```
git cherry-pick HEAD..develop
```

This has no merge conflicts (ever) because these commits easily apply here, so now we have:

```
       o'-o'-A'-C'-D'-E'  <-- fixup (HEAD)
      /
     | o--o--A--C--D--E   <-- develop
     |/       \
...--*         M--F--G--H   <-- br2
      \       /
       o--o--B
```

We can now do the merge with `git merge br2`.  The merge base here is commit `*`, not commit `A`—commit `A` isn't *on* `fixup`—so the merge has the desired source snapshot:

```
       o'-o'-A'-C'-D'-E'----M2  <-- fixup (HEAD)
      /                    /
     | o--o--A--C--D--E   /  <-- develop
     |/       \          /
...--*         M--F--G--H   <-- br2
      \       /
       o--o--B
```

We're now ready to do one last merge, with:

```
git checkout develop
git merge fixup
```

The merge base of these two commits is commit `*` again, so Git compares `*` vs `E` to see what we changed, and `*` vs `M2` to see what "they" changed.  What "they" changed includes everything we changed, so with luck, this merge goes well, and makes a new commit automatically:

```
       o'-o'-A'-C'-D'-E'----M2  <-- fixup
      /                    /  \
     | o--o--A--C--D--E---/----M3  <-- develop (HEAD)
     |/       \          /
...--*         M--F--G--H   <-- br2
      \       /
       o--o--B
```

We can now delete the *name* `fixup` entirely.  All we have done is add new commits: one to `develop`, and a whole new chain that we called `fixup` while we were doing it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped me a lot. I had a little bit more complicated case with 225 commits after mistake `M` merge commit and about 50 commits of 225 were merge commits. Merge commits complicate the cherry-picking process. So I create a new branch and rebased there all commits after `M` commit.

Answer (score 0):

If the commit is published, but not really *shared* (for example : if no one else on your team has its work depending on `broken-branch`), you are perhaps in a situation where you can force push :

```
# spot <good sha> in the history of 'broken-branch' :
git push origin --force-with-lease <good sha>:broken-branch

# additionally, fix your local repo and your colleague's local repo
```

---

Otherwise : you can run `git restore` to create a new commit on top of the merge, with the exact same content as what was on `broken-branch` before the merge :

```
# again : spot <good sha> in the history of 'broken-branch' :
git restore <good sha>
git commit
git push
```

*note* : `git restore` was added fairly recently to git (v2.27), if you are stuck with an older git and can't upgrade, replace it with :

```
git read-tree <good sha>
git commit
...
```

Comment: `git restore <hash>` expects file name as parameter. It says 
`error: pathspec '<hash>' did not match any file(s) known to git`

Answer (score 0):

Is this the last commit in your branch?
If yes - you can do the following: `git reset --hard HEAD~1` and then `git push -f`

If not - you can try with: `git rebase -i HEAD~{X}`

*X* is the number of commits from the last commit in the branch to the commit you want to revert.

Then you can try and drop the commit.

Comment: This is not the last commit :(